# Problem with changing color in PHP variable using CSS

Tags: php, html, css

I am having a problem in switching colors with PHP variables using css class. I want to change color of the text of an error message under a form box on a wrong form input. The initial color of the text of the form's message is green, if it is an error than it should change the message text color into red without  moving anything on the screen. Somehow it is not switching.

CSS:

```
.fcol { color: green; }
.ferr { color: red; }
```

HTML:

```
<form method="post" class="formbox" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" >
       <div>
           <label for="fname"> First Name</label> <br />
           <input type="text" name="fname" value="<?php echo $fname;?>" required> <br />
           <span style="font-size:14px" class="<?php echo $class; ?>" > <?php echo $nameErr;?> </span>
   </div>  <br />          
   <div> <input type="submit" name="submit" class="buttons" value="Submit"> </div>
 </form>
```

PHP:

```
 $class = "fcol"; 
 $nameErr = "Only letters please!";
 if ( $_SERVER[ "REQUEST_METHOD" ] == "POST" ) {
      if ( empty( $_POST[ "fname" ] ) ) {
           $nameErr = "Name is required";
      } else {
           $fname = cleanvar( $_POST[ "fname" ] );
           if ( !preg_match( "/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/", $fname ) ) {
               $class = "ferr";  /* Here I am having problem. This code being not read */
               $nameErr = "Only letters please=> "; 
           } 
      }
 }

 function cleanvar( $userinput ) {
      $inp = trim( $userinput );
      $inp = stripslashes( $userinput );
      $inp = htmlspecialchars( $userinput );
      return $inp;
 }
```

Comment: After you submit your form, look at the HTML source.  Do you see the class text has changed?

Comment: @James: No class code doesn't change. This is the main problem.

Comment: Is there really a space in `< form`?  That would break your form.

Comment: I think it just happened while posting on stack. it is fine in the original code. let me fix it.

Comment: So when you submit an improper name, how far into the code do you get? Using die() or echo() statements, are you getting inside the first IF? Then the ELSE? Then the preg_match IF?

Comment: works fine for me. If I input numbers, the class is ferr. If I enter only letters its fcol.

Comment: I have to ask, are you running the PHP *before* outputting the HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see the result on https://www.highgraderocks.com/reg/stof.php. This will be for a short time.

CSS:

```
.fcol {
    color: green;
}
.ferr {
    color: red;
}
```

HTML:

```
 <form method="post" class="formbox" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
       <div>
           <label for="fname"> First Name</label>
           <br />
           <input type="text" name="fname" value="<?php echo $fname;?>" required>
           <br />
           <span style="font-size:14px" class="<?php echo $class; ?>" > <?php echo $nameErr . "  i = " .  $i;?> </span>
      </div>
            
      <br />
      <div>
           <input type="submit" name="submit" class="buttons" value="Submit"> 
      </div>
 </form>
```

PHP:

```
 $i = 0; //Used index for counting outside of the if statement
 if ( $_SERVER[ "REQUEST_METHOD" ] == "POST" ) {
      if ( empty( $_POST[ "fname" ] ) ) {
           $nameErr = "Name is required";
      } else {
           $fname = cleanvar( $_POST[ "fname" ] );
           if ( !preg_match( "/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/", $fname ) ) {
               $i = 1; //If any non-letter then index for the error — red text
               $nameErr = "Only letters please=> " . $class . "  i = ". $i; 
           } else {
               $i = 0; //index for only letters — green
           }
      }
 }

 function cleanvar( $userinput ) {
      $inp = trim( $userinput );
      $inp = stripslashes( $userinput );
      $inp = htmlspecialchars( $userinput );
      return $inp;
 }

//It was the condition out side of if condition.
if ($i !== 0 ) {
    $class = 'ferr'; 
} else {
    $class = 'fcol';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It works for me. Here's my code, and I only added in the `$fname` default to blank value.

```
<head>
<style>
.fcol { color: green; }
.ferr { color: red; }
</style>
</head>
<?php
    $fname = '';
 $class = "fcol"; 
 $nameErr = "Only letters please!";
 if ( $_SERVER[ "REQUEST_METHOD" ] == "POST" ) {
      if ( empty( $_POST[ "fname" ] ) ) {
           $nameErr = "Name is required";
      } else {
           $fname = cleanvar( $_POST[ "fname" ] );
           if ( !preg_match( "/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/", $fname ) ) {
               $class = "ferr";  /* Here I am having problem. This code being not read */
               $nameErr = "Only letters please"; 
           } 
      }
 }

 function cleanvar( $userinput ) {
      $inp = trim( $userinput );
      $inp = stripslashes( $userinput );
      $inp = htmlspecialchars( $userinput );
      return $inp;
 }

?>

<form method="post" class="formbox" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" >
       <div>
           <label for="fname"> First Name</label> <br />
           <input type="text" name="fname" value="<?php echo $fname;?>" required> <br />
           <span style="font-size:14px" class="<?php echo $class; ?>" > <?php echo $nameErr;?> </span>
   </div>  <br />          
   <div> <input type="submit" name="submit" class="buttons" value="Submit"> </div>
 </form>
```

Comment: No it didn't change the color of the message under the form.

Comment: That's strange, it does for me. [with non-alpha characters](https://snipboard.io/yADoFe.jpg) versus [with only alpha characters](https://snipboard.io/v6EIkT.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I cleaned up the code and got it working on a local PHP Web server. The main change I made was to check if $fname is set and not empty in the form. I also edited some of the texts, which were incorrect, and removed the "required" attr from the name field for testing:

The code is below, and here is a link to a working version that doesn't require submitting a form. Just change the $fname var at the top and execute:

https://onlinephp.io/c/e0759

```
<?php
 $class = "fcol"; 
 $nameErr = "Name is valid";
 
 if ($_SERVER[ "REQUEST_METHOD" ] == "POST") {
      if ( empty( $_POST[ "fname" ] ) ) {
           $nameErr = "Name is required";
      } else {
           $fname = cleanvar( $_POST[ "fname" ] );
           if ( !preg_match( "/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/", $fname ) ) {
               $class = "ferr";  /* Here I am having problem. This code being not read */
               $nameErr = "Only letters please"; 
           } 
      }
 }

 function cleanvar( $userinput ) {
      $inp = trim( $userinput );
      $inp = stripslashes( $userinput );
      $inp = htmlspecialchars( $userinput );
      return $inp;
 }
?>

<style>
     .fcol { background: green; color:#fff; }
     .ferr { background: red; color:#fff; }
</style>

<form method="post" class="formbox" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" >
       <div>
           <label for="fname"> First Name</label> <br />
           <input type="text" name="fname" value="<?php echo isset($fname) && !empty($fname) ? $fname : '';?>" > <br />
           <span style="font-size:14px" class="<?php echo $class; ?>" > <?php echo $nameErr;?> </span>
   </div>  <br />          
   <div> <input type="submit" name="submit" class="buttons" value="Submit"> </div>
 </form>
```

Comment: I don't want to change the background color, but message under the form input box.

Comment: @user6642297 The code I wrote changes the bg of only the little block behind the message, but you can change it to `color` instead and remove the `color:#fff` if you just want to change the text.

Comment: Your code is doing the same thing, which my code is doing. It does not change the message color under the input box.

Comment: @user6642297 Click on the URL link to the sandbox and click Execute. The name is "Jerry Seinfeld" so in the HTML output, you can see the class is "fcol." Now change it to "Jerry Seinfeld1" and execute again. The class is now "ferr." Let me know if you don't see that.

Comment: I copied the entire code and ran it, but it didn't work.

Comment: @user6642297 Yeah, there must be an error in your overall code, or something is missing, or the scope/order is off.

Comment: let me go through all the logic and scope of the code. Thanks.

Comment: I just fixed it. There was some logic problem.  I changed a few things and now it is changing the colors, if no error then green and with error the text color changes into the red.  I am going to post the answer for the review. Thanks for your all help.